# Ошибка при разборе аргументов кортежа

Tags: python, функции, tuple

Имеется следующий код:

```
#Определение функций foo1 и foo2
def foo():
  return 1, 2
def foo1():
  return 2, 3

#Вызов функций foo1 и foo2
a, b = foo() + foo1()
```

Данный фрагмент кода выдает ошибку следующего вида:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Обе функции возвращают кортежи с  двумя полями, при суммировании кортежей создается временный кортеж с двумя полями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo() + foo1()` это четыре значения.

Можете проверить через

```
print(foo() + foo1())
```